# how can I customize token validation response in wso2?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

getting following response as Json

```
{
    "fault": {
        "code": 900901,
        "message": "Invalid Credentials",
        "description": "Access failure for API: *** version: 1.0 status: (900901) - Invalid Credentials. Make sure you have provided the correct security credentials"
    }
}
```

when I choose content-type as application/soap+xml, we get following response

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <soapenv:Code>
                <soapenv:Value>soapenv:Client</soapenv:Value>
            </soapenv:Code>
            <soapenv:Reason>
                <soapenv:Text xml:lang="en">Authentication Failure</soapenv:Text>
            </soapenv:Reason>
            <soapenv:Detail>Access failure for API: /goods-shipment/1.0, version: 1.0 status: (900901) - Invalid Credentials</soapenv:Detail>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

how do i add specific code block as code 401 to SOAP response

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom error messages by adding a sequence. Follow this documentation. https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/troubleshooting/error-handling/#custom-error-messages

Comment: how can I change it for a specific API, if Observe properly response type is soap 1.2

Comment: You have to write some logic inside the sequence to apply this for a specific API.

Comment: could you please share any sample it's extremely urgent for me

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have samples on this matter.